# Como obtener el valor de una etiqueta <a>VALOR DESEADO</a> con python

Tags: html, python, twitter-api

Estoy trabajando con el API de Twitter para python, en la informacion que me devuelve esta hay una denominada 'source' esta devulve la informacion de la siguiente manera:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/download/iphone" rel="nofollow">Twitter for iPhone</a>
```

Yo unicamente quiero la parte donde indica desde que dispostivo fue enviado el tweet, por ejemplo, para este caso yo unicamente quisiera 'Twitter for iPhone' Sin embargo esta cambia ya que hay miles de fuentes desde donde se puede enviar un tuit, por lo que remplazar o eliminar por medio de String no es una solucion.

Comment: ¿Hay algún patrón que permita reconocer la línea con esa información?

Comment: Ya le pude dar solucion, muchas gracias